# Root Samsung Galaxy S2 with unconventional kernel version

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, rooting

My Galaxy S2 is running Android 4.1.2. I am following the howto [here](http://nm7.org/how-root-samsung-galaxy-s2-linux). I am trying to look for the corresponding CF-Root download, by looking in the [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1103399) forum. The problem is that the kernel version of my device does not match the format given in the forum. Here are the details of my kernel:

```
Model Number     : GT-I9100
Baseband Version : I9100BULS1
Kernel-Version   : 3.0.31-889555 dpi@DELL228 #3 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 31 14:48:54 KST 2013
Buildnummer      : JZO54K.I9100XWLSD
```

How can I choose a CF-Root download based on that kernel version?

Comment: Following the `rooting` tag you've used brings you to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) (first item in "faq" there), which links two guides for the S2. Have you checked if one of those fits your needs? If not: At the end of that index, several rooting methods are listed, some of them covering multiple devices. Anything fitting there for you? If still "no", which model is your S2 (GT-I9100P, GT-I9100G)?

Comment: @Izzy From the buildnumber in the quote in the question, it seems like OP has i9100 - the International S2.

Comment: @Izzy: I have added `Model Number` and `Baseband Version`. With the guides you link to I have the same problem as with the `xda-developers` forum: the codes in my phone do not match any of the codes covered on any of the guides, so I am not able to choose any of the available guides to proceed. Since rooting is *dangerous*, I am reluctant to simply try one of the guides. My phone has been acquired in Germany, in case that matters.

Comment: If a factory-reset isn't "dangerous" for you, I'd say rooting isn't, either. I'd try one of the "root many" methods for JB -- in the worst case it doesn't work, then it cannot mess up anything in the system (just in "userspace", which is cureable by a factory-reset).